# API JSON response: get key value

Tags: java, json, api, groovy

Below is the response message (JSON) from an API endpoint.
I need to parse the JSON response, and I need to retrieve the RequestID key.

```
{
  "Status":1,
  "RequestID":"29d2d52c-e8fe-447f-9ee1-15e4624be58f",
  "Data":[
    {
      "RegNumber":"ASD3948506",
      "CaseData":{
        "CaseResult":{
          "Message":"success",
          "RequestID":"8C15473C0F7771F410928D5D91362B80"
        },
        "ErrorMessageList":[
        ]
      }
    }]
}
```

Below is my code to retrieve the `RequestID`[Inside the CaseResult]

```
JSONObject actualJson = new JSONObject(response.getResponseText())
def requestID = actualJson.get('Data[0].CaseData.CaseResult.RequestID')
```

When I executed it, I got the below error message.

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["Data[0].CaseData.CaseResult.RequestID"] not found.
```

Could any one provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query values using that kind of string:

```
'Data[0].CaseData.CaseResult.RequestID'
```

You will get null as result

[image]

### Explicit access to the values

Using **JsonSlurper** you can parse any valid string json to a groovy object.

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def object = jsonSlurper.parse("{....}")
println object
println object.Status
println object["Status"]
println object["Data"][0]["CaseResult"]["RequestId"]
```

[image]

## Jsonpath

This is the only library capable to use string queries to get values from the json:

```
$.Data[0].CaseData.CaseResult.RequestID
```

```
String json = "...";
String jsonPathExpression = "$.Data[0].CaseData.CaseResult.RequestID"; 
JsonNode jsonNode = JsonPath.parse(json).read(jsonPathExpression, JsonNode.class);
```

[image]

## References

- https://jsonpath.com
- https://groovyconsole.appspot.com
- https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly query the string from json object. Use below code to get the RequestId.

```
try {
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
  String requestId = obj.getJSONArray("Data")
      .getJSONObject(0)
      .getJSONObject("CaseData")
      .getJSONObject("CaseResult")
      .getString("RequestID");
  System.out.println(requestId);
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try library *Josson*. The query syntax is the same as your expected.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(response.getResponseText());
String requestId = josson.getString("Data[0].CaseData.CaseResult.RequestID");
System.out.println(requestId);
// Output: 8C15473C0F7771F410928D5D91362B80
```